# sqljocky - MySql - communication with MySql

Tags: mysql, dart

I'm looking at sqljocky for use with MySql, and checking to see how it "works". There doesn't appear to be any "C" code and it appears to use sockets.

Is that correct, and could someone who knows, elaborate a little bit for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote SQLjocky, and you are correct - there is no C code in SQLjocky, it is completely written in Dart, and uses sockets to communicate with the MySQL server. The protocol is documented to varying levels of usefulness at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html

Comment: Is SQLJocky ready for production use or were you just testing dart possibilities?

Comment: @Gero I certainly intend that it should eventually be production ready, and I'm using it in some of my own project successfully, but it is still in active development and hasn't been thoroughly tested yet. Also, with the SDK still in a state of flux, there's a good chance that the SQLJocky API will also change before getting to a 1.0 release.

Comment: @JamesOts. Thanks for the info. I installed it and the test ran without a single hitch, so that's encouraging. Thanks also for the link that explains the protocol. Looks good thus far, so I hope you see it through. Not sure about MySql, I did check it out years ago, but obviously it has improved. I'm using the community version because I thought that it may have a more liberal license, but I don't know. But hey, it's gr8 to be able to access a database and at this stage it looks promising.

Comment: @JamesOts, Package sqljocky has no versions that match 0.14.1 derived from:
- server depends on version 0.14.1

Can you help?